# Regarding Work and Energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

> When work is done, there is a transfer of energy

But my textbook says the *vice versa isn't true*. May I know such a situation in which energy is transferred even if no work is done?

Comment: If you hold a bomb and move horizontally, you move the bomb (and its associated chemical potential energy) but do not gain or lose potential energy, and therefore do no work. Does that count?

Comment: Heat transfer may not be the best example, although it may be part of what your textbook means. On the atomic scale, work is certainly being done when particles exchange kinetic energy, even if on the macro scale we would say the thermodynamic work is zero. Likewise chemical changes e.g. biosynthesis, digestion, involve mechanical work on the atomic scale. Aside from taking something with internal energy like Allure's bomb (or a tensioned spring, or a molecule of glucose) and physically moving it somewhere else, I can't think of anything.

Comment: What kind of textbook is it?

Comment: my school textbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of transfer of heat from one body to another, there may be no work done.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate it a bit why will heat transfer require no work?

Comment: @Shashaank Essentially heat energy in a system is proportional to temperature.  Let's say you have a bowl of water at 323K and an object at 293K.  The object has thermal energy ∝ 293K, but after it's been submerged and the temperature becomes uniform, it has thermal energy ∝ 323K.  The thermal energy has risen, but the water did no work on the object by heating it.  Evidently, since the object doesn't move when heating, it isn't experiencing mechanical work.  

Other forms of work exist, but in this case there isn't another form of work I'm aware of that would be done on the cold object.

Comment: Thank you soo much @Paul Dilley

Comment: Happy to help!  Glad it was helpful to you.